# Connect server with internal ip adress using IdTcpClient

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe8

I have problem connecting server that is in internal network(e.g wifi network).Im using rad studio idtcpclient

```
IdTcpClient1.Host:='ip'
IdTcpClient1.Connect;
```

But with what I need replace ip to connect this  server?

Comment: Why don't you use local IP address of that computer?

Comment: The server's IP address, clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If the client is inside the same WiFi network as the server, the client can connect to the server's LAN IP address directly.

If the client is outside of the WiFi network, the client cannot connect to the server's LAN IP address directly.  It must connect to the WiFi router's public WAN IP instead, and the router must be configured with port forwarding enabled to pass inbound connections to the server.  If the router supports uPNP, the server app can dynamically create port forwarding rules for itself, otherwise the router admin must configure them manually.